# Python Crash Course Game showing not showing images correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to solve this issue where all images are just completely messed up and don't show properly.

It doesn't pop up any error so it is hard to traceback the cause for this: [Here is a more detailed image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUazm.png)

The code is as follows:

main code (alien_invasion.py):

```
import sys
import game_functions as gf
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
from pygame.sprite import Group
from alien import Alien
from game_stats import GameStats
from button import Button

def run_game():
    # Initialize pygame, settings, and screen object.
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    play_button = Button(ai_settings, screen, "Play")

    stats = GameStats(ai_settings)
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)

    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    # Make a ship.
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)
    aliens = Group()
    bullets = Group()

    # Background color
    bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
    gf.create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, aliens, ship)


    while True:

        gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets, stats, play_button)
        if stats.game_active:
            ship.update(ai_settings)
            gf.update_aliens(ai_settings, aliens, ship, stats, screen, bullets)
            gf.update_bullets(bullets, aliens, ai_settings, screen, ship)

        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, bullets, screen, ship, aliens, stats, play_button)

        if not stats.game_active:
            play_button.draw_button()

    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)

    ship.blitme(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()




run_game()
```

Alien code (alien.py):

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Alien(Sprite):

    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        super(Alien, self).__init__()

        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        self.image = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\alien invasion\alien.bmp')
        #Load the alien image and set its rect attribute
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        #Start each new alienn near the top left of the screen
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height
        #Store the alien's exact position
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)

    def blitme(self):
        #Draw the alien at its current location
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def update(self):
        self.x += (self.ai_settings.alien_speed_factor * self.ai_settings.fleet_direction)
        self.rect.x = self.x

    def check_edges(self):
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        if self.rect.right >= screen_rect.right:
            return True
        elif self.rect.left <= 0:
            return True
```

Bullet code (bullet.py):

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Bullet(Sprite):

    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, ship):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, ai_settings.bullet_width, ai_settings.bullet_height)
        self.rect.centerx = ship.rect.centerx
        self.rect.top = ship.rect.top
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)
        self.color = ai_settings.bullet_color
        self.ship_speed_factor = ai_settings.bullet_speed_factor

    def update(self):
        self.y -= self.ship_speed_factor
        self.rect.y = self.y


    def draw_bullet(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

Button code (button.py):

```
import pygame.font

class Button():
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, msg):
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.width, self.height = 200, 50
        self.button_color = (0, 250, 0)
        self.text_color = (255, 255, 255)
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
        self.rect.center = (self.screen_rect.center)
        self.prep_msg(msg)

    def prep_msg(self, msg):
        self.msg_image = self.font.render(msg, True, self.text_color, self.button_color)
        self.msg_image_rect = self.msg_image.get_rect()
        self.msg_image_rect.center = self.rect.center

    def draw_button(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.button_color, self.rect)
        self.screen.blit(self.msg_image, self.msg_image_rect)
```

Game function code (game_functions.py):

```
import sys
import pygame
from bullet import Bullet
from alien import Alien
from time import sleep

def check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets, stats, play_button):

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            check_play_button(stats, play_button, mouse_x, mouse_y)

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event,ship, ai_settings, screen, bullets)

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(event, ship)


def update_screen(ai_settings, bullets, screen, ship, aliens, stats, play_button):

    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()



    aliens.draw(screen)
    ship.blitme(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

def check_keydown_events(event, ship, ai_settings, screen, bullets):
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
    elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
        sys.exit()

def fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
        if len(bullets) < ai_settings.bullets_allowed:
            new_bullet =  Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
            bullets.add(new_bullet)


def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False


def update_bullets(bullets, aliens, ai_settings, screen, ship):
    bullets.update()
    collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullets, aliens, True, True)
    if len(aliens) == 0:
        bullets.empty()
        create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, aliens, ship)
    for bullet in bullets.copy():
        if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
            bullets.remove(bullet)


def create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, aliens, ship):
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
    alien_width = alien.rect.width
    number_aliens_x = get_number_aliens_x(ai_settings, alien.rect.width)
    number_rows = get_number_rows(ai_settings, ship.rect.height, alien.rect.height)
    for row_number in range(number_rows):

        for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
            create_alien(ai_settings, screen, aliens, alien_number, row_number)

def get_number_aliens_x(ai_settings, alien_width):
    available_space_x = ai_settings.screen_width - 2 * alien_width
    number_aliens_x = int(available_space_x / (2 * alien_width))
    return number_aliens_x

def create_alien(ai_settings, screen, aliens, alien_number, row_number):
    alien = Alien(ai_settings, screen)
    alien_width = alien.rect.width
    alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
    alien.rect.x = alien.x
    alien.rect.y = alien.rect.height + 2 * alien.rect.height * row_number
    aliens.add(alien)

def get_number_rows(ai_settings, ship_height, alien_height):
    available_space_y = (ai_settings.screen_height - (3 * alien_height) - (ship_height))
    number_rows = int(available_space_y / (2 * alien_height))
    return number_rows

def update_aliens(ai_settings, aliens, ship, stats, screen, bullets):
    check_fleet_edges(ai_settings, aliens)
    aliens.update()
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(ship, aliens):
        ship_hit(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)
    check_aliens_bottom(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)

def check_fleet_edges(ai_settings, aliens):
    for alien in aliens.sprites():
        if alien.check_edges():
            change_fleet_direction(ai_settings, aliens)
            break

def change_fleet_direction(ai_settings, aliens):
    for alien in aliens.sprites():
        alien.rect.y += ai_settings.fleet_drop_speed
    ai_settings.fleet_direction *= -1

def ship_hit(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets):
    if stats.ships_left > 0:
        stats.ships_left -= 1
        aliens.empty()
        bullets.empty()
        create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, aliens, ship)
        ship.center_ship
        sleep(0.5)
    else:
        stats.game_active = False


def check_aliens_bottom(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets):
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    for alien in aliens.sprites():
        if alien.rect.bottom >= screen_rect.bottom:
            ship_hit(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)
            break

def check_play_button(stats, play_button, mouse_x, mouse_y):
    if play_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_x, mouse_y):
        stats.game_active = True
```

Game stats (game_stats.py):

```
class GameStats():
    def __init__(self, ai_settings):
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        self.reset_stats()
        self.game_active = True

    def reset_stats(self):
        self.ships_left = self.ai_settings.ship_limit
```

Settings code (settings.py):

```
class Settings():
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
        self.ship_speed_factor = 10
        self.ship_limit = 3

        self.bullet_speed_factor = 3
        self.bullet_width = 3
        self.bullet_height = 12
        self.bullet_color = (60, 60, 60)
        self.bullets_allowed = 3

        self.alien_speed_factor = 1
        self.fleet_drop_speed = 10
        self.fleet_x_margin = 70
        self.fleet_y_margin = 70
        self.fleet_direction = -1
```

Ship code (ship.py):

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
class Ship(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        super(Ship, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        self.image = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\alien invasion\ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)
        self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor



    def update(self, ai_settings):
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.rect.centerx += 1
            self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
            self.rect.centerx -= 1


    def blitme(self, screen):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def center_ship(self):
        self.center = self.screen_rect.centerx
```

Any help would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Simple change needed. Clear the screen before drawing the aliens.

```
while True:

    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)   #  <<<<<<<  clear screen first
    gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets, stats, play_button)
    if stats.game_active:
        ship.update(ai_settings)
        gf.update_aliens(ai_settings, aliens, ship, stats, screen, bullets)
        gf.update_bullets(bullets, aliens, ai_settings, screen, ship)

    gf.update_screen(ai_settings, bullets, screen, ship, aliens, stats, play_button)

    if not stats.game_active:
        play_button.draw_button()
```